# jquery - find id after using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have button that print form with data accourding different id.
each form contain unique ID.

The problem is that the main page don't find those IDs

js (data display form)

```
$(document).on("click", ".e-manage", function(e){

var element     = $(this);
var attracID    = element.attr("data-attracID");

data = "attracID=" + attracID;

$.ajax ({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'attraction-manage.php',
  data: data,
  async: false,
  success: function (data) 
      {
        $("#attrac"+attracID).append(data);
      }
  });

    e.preventDefault();
```

});

```
$(document).on("click", ".close_form", function(e){
    formID = $(this).parents("form").attr('id');
    $("#attrac-form-"+formID).hide();  **// this part doesn't works**

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Data results:

```
<form id="attrac-form-<?PHP echo $mainIndex['id'] ?>" action="#">
</form>

<form id="attrac-form-<?PHP echo $mainIndex['id'] ?>" action="#">
</form>

<form id="attrac-form-<?PHP echo $mainIndex['id'] ?>" action="#">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `close_form` ?

Comment: I dont think you need to do this $("#attrac-form-"+formID).hide(); You can directly write `$('#'+formID).hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the string, your code will be like that:

```
$("#"+formID).hide();
```

like Furquan Khan said.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which HTML element has `close_form` class.
But still, to give you a direction,

```
$(document).on("click", ".close_form", function(e){
    formID = $(this).parents("form").attr('id');
    $(formID).hide();  **// Do not need the string before `formID` variable as it already contains it.**

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to do this

`$("#attrac-form-"+formID).hide();`

You can directly write

`$('#'+formID).hide();`

You already got the id of the form using `formID = $(this).parents("form").attr('id');`